# BigSur Notes app - how to search for 'aws'?

Tags: notes.app

When I search for 'aws' in Notes app, it shows all matches for 'was'.

This pretty much makes it impossible to find notes with 'aws', given that vast majority of my notes have the word 'was' in them.  How can I turn off this strange behavior?

Comment: When I search in Notes for 'aws', it shows two result lists. 'Top Hits' which has results for aws and 'Notes' which has results for was, ass and awes.

Answer (score 1):

You can try searching using Spotlight Search. Spotlight searches Notes and will list the Notes it finds. I just tried it and it found "aws" in my Notes. And it didn't include "was".